# Fuzzy merging in R

Tags: r, fuzzy-search

How to join two objects, if they are semantically different?

```
1.Tire 195 / 75R16C Cordiant Business CA 107 / 105R all-season
2.195/75 R16C lid CORDIANT Business CA
```

But this is the same product, because matches its article `195/75 R16С`

and one example

```
1.185/75 R16C lid Forward Professional 156 ASHK tubeless
2.The tire `185/75 R16С` С-156
```

`185/75 R16C`

New question aboit this topic
[R:Error in compare.linkage : Data sets have different format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47510101/rerror-in-compare-linkage-data-sets-have-different-format)

Comment: I think I can help, but it isn't clear to me in the example above where one object starts and the other starts.

Comment: @BradCannell. I edited post and indicated number  of objects

Comment: @missuse, yes, but i can't provide combinations, it's many much combination 
'(1.)6,50-16 y-387-1
(2.)9.00-20 ВЛ-45
and so on there are many objects'

Comment: can you provide any solutions, cause my dataset is not english

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So here is a solution using the [RecordLinkage package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RecordLinkage/index.html). I think this does what you want.

Example data:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(RecordLinkage)

df_01 <- tibble(
  product = c("Tire 195 / 75R16C Cordiant Business CA 107 / 105R all-season",
              "Something else")
)
df_02 <- tibble(
  product = c("195/75 R16C lid CORDIANT Business CA", 
              "Different Product")
)
```

The details of this next part are probably best left to the RecordLinkage documentation:

```
rpairs_jar <- compare.linkage(df_01, df_02,
                              strcmp = c("product"),
                              strcmpfun = jarowinkler)

rpairs_epiwt <- epiWeights(rpairs_jar)

getPairs(rpairs_epiwt, max.weight = Inf, min.weight = -Inf)

   id                                                      product    Weight
1   1 Tire 195 / 75R16C Cordiant Business CA 107 / 105R all-season          
2   1                         195/75 R16C lid CORDIANT Business CA 0.6135377
3                                                                           
4   2                                               Something else          
5   2                                            Different Product 0.4827264
6                                                                           
7   1 Tire 195 / 75R16C Cordiant Business CA 107 / 105R all-season          
8   2                                            Different Product 0.4586156
9                                                                           
10  2                                               Something else          
11  1                         195/75 R16C lid CORDIANT Business CA 0.4320106
```

So, this results in a probability of two rows matching. As you can see, the rows you want to match return the highest weight.

Comment: Brad, very well.

Comment: @D.Joe I’m glad this worked for you. Do you mind clicking the check mark to accept the answer, please?

Comment: it' s done)last request, i gonna join two tables, is it possible  for these weights to create one column where is indicated that it's weight is good match. for example after joining we must have thats fields id, х1,x2,x3.. ,weight, match (0- bad much, 1 middle match, 3 good match

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly. If you are joining tables with a common id, why do you need the fuzzy matching?

Comment: it is not common id)) semantic it is different, but article  is commom, i must join to get price column. one table has id with objects and article, second table has id with same article, but different sematic and price column))

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble visualizing your scenario. Maybe you can post a reproducible example?

Comment: i have new question about it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47510101/rerror-in-compare-linkage-data-sets-have-different-format. Your code in this example doesn't work